# Form submit returns response with contentType as application/json instead of text/html

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I submit a form using jQuery with post method.

```html
<form action="/controller/ActionName" id="formDetail" method="post" onsubmit="" target="_top">
    <input name="name" type="hidden" value="name123" />
</form>


/* jQuery code to submit form*/

$("#formDetail").submit();
```

Controller

```cs
public ViewResult ActionName(string name)
{
    // rest of code 
    return View("viewName", model);
}
```

The controller action returns view properly. But browser receives response with contentType as `application/json` and complete html markup in response is displayed on screen(actually wrapped inside a `<pre>` tag)

If jQuery code is replaced with below it works perfectly, response has contentType as `text/html` and  proper html page is displayed.

```
window.location.href = '/controller/action?name=name';
```

Tried setting `Response.ContentType = "text/html"` as suggested in similar questions on SO but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what is happening, but still not sure why.

When form is submitted, it hits the action `controller/ActionName` and returns html view. This view contains `@Html.Action("anotherAction")`. Now this `anotherAction` has two variants - HttpGet and HttpPost. Since I am doing a form submit with POST method, `@Html.Action("anotherAction")` is hitting the `HttpPost` variant which is returning a JSON response(so content type `Application/json`).

So the content type for whole response is overridden by a final call in the process to `anotherAction` which is returning JSON. But I am still not able to find why this happens.

You can fix this behavior by changing form's method to `get`. But in my case that `POST` exist for a reason and I had to change multiple things to make the original form submit work.